# Autodesk forge! How to download drawings pdf with markup?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

I want to download the pdf file that I opened by the extension of autodesk forge and markuped.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to capture a screenshot of both the PDF and markups (see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/screenshot-markups) for details), but obviously you'd need to zoom out to get the whole page and you'd lose all the meta data as well.

And to truly append the markups to the PDF you may save the SVG string (`markupExt.generateData()`) and then render them to the PDF, see below to get you started:

- http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf
- https://github.com/alafr/SVG-to-PDFKit

Comment: Thank you for your response, I want the quality pdf file and I've tried to take screenshots with markup but the img returns the uexpected quality.

Comment: I've tried to render svg to the pdf but I don't know the reason why svg created from markupExt.generateData() can't be rendered to pdf. I've tried testing some other svg files and they are rendered.

Comment: Yeah the svg that generateData() produces is not a valid svg. I have a potential solution im working on but am still searching for some sort of scale factor i'm missing